# MySQL error when migrating to Quarkus 3 using Hibernate Reactive Panache

Tags: mysql, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-hibernate-reactive

I'm currently trying to migrate from Quarkus 2 to Quarkus 3.

I performed all the needed changes and the code now compiles with Quarkus 3.

I'm using Hibernate Reactive Panache with the Repository Pattern.

I have one entity that needs to fetch data from a lot of tables, so the entities it needs are using `FetchType.EAGER`. To make matters worse, this one entity can have multiple types, so I basically have 4 subclasses of this abstract class and I was serializing them all in one table using the annotations `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` and `@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")` and on each subclass using `@DiscriminatorValue(<name>)`.

With Quarkus 2 the query to retrieve all data was able to retrieve them all, but now with Quarkus 3 and the `listAll`method I get a `GenericJDBCException` stating `Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join`, even though I haven't changed the logic here, just went from a `findAll` to a `listAll`.

Here is a picture of the ER Diagram with the classes that are fetched from this class (named `Request`).

[image]

Each `RequestType` subclass has a different amount of `RequestSlot`

Any ideas on what can I do or on what is happening here?

Thanks in advance